# Document.lastModified

Tags: веб-программирование, api, dom

Есть такая штука: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.lastModified. Но я не пойму, откуда она узнает, когда была последний раз модифицированна страница? В смысле вот как ее на хостинг положили и не трогали? Или как?

Answer (score 1):

По отданному сервером заголовку last-modified

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP

В случае отдачи статичной страницы этот заголовк вероятнее всего будет проставлен согласно времени последней модификации файла html